# error while using visual studio InstallShield

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, installshield

I'm getting error while using InstallShield to create a Windows Form application setup.

When I run the build I get the error

```
"The DefaultDir column of the Directory table includes characters that are not available on code page 1252"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Ugh, that's sad.  InstallShield is a "solution" that forever seems to create two new problems.  [Read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant There's a difference between creating problems and identifying them. (I am biased, as I implemented the check being quoted.)

Comment: I am biased too.  Why don't you educate us an explain the reason why you could not automatically take care of this?

Comment: @HansPassant Windows Installer uses ANSI encoded storage, and has problems with UTF-8 that the tool shouldn't automatically subscribe you to. What CP-1252 character should a tool automatically replace a Chinese character with? (Or, a more common case, what Chinese code page character should automatically replace the ©, ™ or ® symbols?)

Answer (score 3):

You are using characters in your default install location path name that are not supported in the default codepage [1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) your installation release is build.

Enable "Build UTF-8 Database" in "Releases" > (YourReleaseName) > "Build"-Tab.

OR maybe better avoid using non latin letters in windows file paths.

Comment: and how can i change the path name?

Comment: It's the INSTALLDIR property in the "General Information" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Base on @user1064248 answer,

Enable "Build UTF-8 Database" in "Releases" > (YourReleaseName) > "Build"-Tab

It worked in my side.

I add image for more detail step. I share for whom concerned.

[image]